# Linearly Independent Set of Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, vector-spaces

Let $\mathbb R^{\mathbb Z^+}$ be the space of infinite sequences of reals. For each $\alpha \in\mathbb R$, let $e^\alpha = (1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3,\alpha^4...)$. Show the set $\{e^{\alpha}\mid\alpha \in\mathbb R\}$ of vectors is linearly independent.

My question is how is $\mathbb R^{\mathbb Z^+}$ related to the set $\{e^{\alpha}\mid\alpha \in\mathbb R\}$ — is it merely reltaed in the sense that the set of vectors is contained in that space?

And to prove it, I suppose I have to show the matrix with these vectors as columns has a non-zero determinant. Is there any shortcut in proving the matrix has a non-zero determinant?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\alpha_1,\ldots\alpha_n,\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n\in\mathbb R$, with $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ distinct, and suppose that$$\beta_1e^{\alpha_1}+\beta_2e^{\alpha_2}+\cdots+\beta_ne^{\alpha_n}=0.$$Then, in particular\begin{multline}\beta_1(1,\alpha_1,{\alpha_1}^2,\ldots,{\alpha_1}^{n-1})+\beta_2(1,\alpha_2,{\alpha_2}^2,\ldots,{\alpha_2}^{n-1})+\cdots+\\+\beta_n(1,\alpha_n,{\alpha_n}^2,\ldots,{\alpha_n}^{n-1})=(0,0,\ldots,0).\end{multline}But if this took place with some $\beta_k\neq0$, then the vectors $(1,\alpha_k,{\alpha_k}^2,\ldots,{\alpha_k}^{n-1})$ would not be linearly independent. However,$$\begin{vmatrix}1&\alpha_1&\ldots&{\alpha_1}^{n-1}\\1&\alpha_2&\ldots&{\alpha_2}^{n-1}\\ \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\1&\alpha_n&\ldots&{\alpha_n}^{n-1}\end{vmatrix}=\prod_{1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n}(\alpha_1-\alpha_j)\neq0$$(this is a [Vandermonde determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)) and therefore the $\beta_k$'s must be all equal to $0$.

Comment: can you explain the statement after "But"?  why is the det that formula?

Comment: and how does that not equal to zero relate the previous $\beta$ formula to show that all $\beta$ have to equal to 0

Comment: I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.

Comment: sorry still a litte confused... so i understand we need to show all $\beta$=0 and if we assume some does not equal to 0 then the vectors would be linearly dependent by definition. But i am confused after the "however" with the matrix, sorry.

Comment: The lines of the matrix are the entries of my vectors. Since the determinant of the matrix is different from $0$, they are linearly independent.

Comment: so my questions are :
1. if det of matrix of row entries of vectors is not 0, then they're linearly independent?
2. if so, why is there any need to write the $\beta$ formula in the first place?
thanks for your help and time

Comment: sorry i got it for the first part of my question that it is a yes but what about part 2 of my question? why cant we just use the matrix to show det is not zero, and directly have the result of linear independence?

Comment: @jamesblack $(\beta_1 ~ \beta_2 ~ \cdots ~ \beta_n)$ multiply the matrix (which is placed after "However") equals zero column matrix.

Comment: That's what I do, isn't it? The determinant is not $0$, and therefore the vectors $(1,\alpha_k,{\alpha_k}^2,\ldots,{\alpha_k}^{n-1})$ are linearly independent and therefore your vectors (the $e^{\alpha_k}$'s) are linearly independent.

Comment: oh got it, so it shows how you got to the matrix. i was just saying is it an okay proof if i just include the part after "however," simply showing the det is not 0, thus the result? (not including anything before the "however"

Comment: this might be a dumb question so apologies in advance

Comment: Have you noticed that my vectors $(1,\alpha_k,{\alpha_k}^2,\ldots,{\alpha_k}^{n-1})$ are *not* your vectors $e^{\alpha_k}$?

Answer (score 2):

**Partial Answer**

Let $C(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}$. It is a vector space.

In fact, $\{e^{\alpha x} = 1 + \alpha x + \frac{(\alpha x)^2}{2!} 
+ \frac{(\alpha x)^3}{3!}  \cdots : \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}$ 
is a linearly independent set of $C(\mathbb{R})$.

(If we choose finite elements in this set, and assume that they are linearly independent, then we can easily derive the contradiction.)

I think the definition of $e^\alpha  = (1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \alpha^3, \ldots)$ 
seems to be related to $e^{\alpha x}$ in $C(\mathbb{R})$.

Assume each $\alpha_i$ is distinct value of $\mathbb{R}$.

${\beta_1}e^{\alpha_1} + {\beta_2} e^{\alpha_2} 
+ \ldots + {\beta_n} e^{\alpha_n} = 0$

$\implies 
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n {\beta_i} {\alpha_i}^m =0 ~~~$ for all $m = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$

$\implies 
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n {\beta_i} ({\alpha_i x})^m =0 ~~~$ 
for all $m = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$

$\implies 
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n {\beta_i} \frac{({\alpha_i x})^m}{m!} =0 ~~~$ 
for all $m = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$

$\implies 
\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{i=1}^n {\beta_i} \frac{({\alpha_i x})^m}{m!} 
= \sum\limits_{i=1}^n {\beta_i} 
\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty  \frac{({\alpha_i x})^m}{m!} 
= \sum\limits_{i=1}^n {\beta_i} 
e^{\alpha_i x}= 0 ~~~$ 
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

**(in the last expression, the change of adding terms should be checked. I think it is true. But it should be checked more rigorously.)**

Therefore if there exists $\{\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_n\}$ which satisfies the first equation and some of which are not zero, then we can say that $\{e^{\alpha_1 x}, \ldots, e^{\alpha_n x}\}$ is linearly dependent in $C(\mathbb{R})$. Contradiction.